# Linear Algebra for Least Square Lines for Data

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Find the least-squares line for the data below by following the steps after the data.

Data Given

The year                  1880     1910     1940     1970     2000

Global Mean Temperature   13.73O   13.72O   13.98O   14.00O   14.51O

A) Give the entries of A and bin Ax=b for this data.

For this part, I put A as v1=(1,1,1,1,1) and v2= (1880,1910,1940,1970,2000) and for b I have (13.73,13.72,13.98,14,14.51)

B) Give the equation whose solution will give the coefficients of the least-squares line.

I got A^tAx=A^tb

Matrix A^t* I have v1= (5,9700) and v2=(9700, 18,827,000)
Matrix A^tb I have (96.94, 135,738,80)

C)Use some appropriate technology to find the coefficients of the least-squares line.

After plugging it in I have x to be (11,298.289 , -5.813)

Can anyone confirm if I did this entire problem correctly or if I missed something.

Comment: You have to left-multiply both sides by $A^T$. This new equation will give you the least squares solution. Here’s a resource: http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf

Comment: But multiplying A*A^T (Year time transpose Year) I get a ridiculously big matrix with big numbers

Comment: @Displayer123 you have the order backwards. "Left-multiply by $A$" means that you end up with $A^TA$.

Comment: Oh duh, thanks! But it corrected to have A as 1 or 2 vectors? 1 vector just being the given data and 2 vectors being V1 as only 1's and V2 being the data given

Comment: @displayer123 you can multiply A*A^T. The dimensions that don't match. You want to solve $A^{T}A \hat{x}=A^{T}b$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your mathematical expressions.